# Faut-il faire les liaisons avec les noms de lettres ?

Tags: prononciation, standard

Entendu en cours de maths

> Soit une application *f* de ℝ dans X
>   [...] `/dɑ̃ziks/`

Ça m'a écorché les oreilles, mais ça paraît logique, puisque *X* c'est `[iks]`. D'autant plus qu'on dit couramment

> y plus deux x
>   [...] `/døziks/`

Quelle est la prononciation standard de ce genre d'enchaînements ?

Comment: Étrangement *+ x* peut se prononcer des 2 manières.

Comment: La question de l'elision se pose aussi — pourquoi ne pas avoir dit _Soit une application _f_ d'**R** dans x_ ?

Comment: Intuitivement, je ne ferais pas la liaison dans _f de R dans Y_ mais je la ferais dans  _x plus deux y_

Comment: Ça m'a l'air d'être une question d'usage… Par exemple pour un polytechnicien je dirais « c'est un *n'*X », on dit aussi « né(e) sous *z'*X » mais pour une variable mathématique j'entends rarement la liaison.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Afin de trouver un point de comparaison : on dit presque toujours « *f* de *x* » ou « une fonction de *x* », plutôt qu'« *f* d'*x* » ou « une fonction d'*x* ». (Et on n'écrit pas ce dernier non plus).

Par ailleurs, en français courant, la contraction ne se fait quasiment jamais non plus :
[image: comparaison des que x]

Je pense donc qu'il n'y a pas lieu de faire la liaison avec *dans*.
Et il y a un cas où il faut à tout prix l'éviter : celui de *η* (éta) qu'il ne faut pas confondre avec ζ (zéta) !

Par ailleurs, je peux confirmer que j'ai beaucoup plus souvent entendu `/dɑ̃.iks/` que `/dɑ̃ziks/`, et je crois que je ne fais jamais la liaison moi-même.

*Ajout suite à l'apparition du contre exemple « deux x »* : Je pense que ce qui casse la liaison c'est le début d'une formule (ou de toute autre entitée qui n'est pas un mot français). La cassure semble naturelle et facilite la compréhension de la phrase ; les liaisons sont cependant souhaitables à l'interieur d'une formule (mais on peut peut-être vouloir séparer certaines sous-formules lorsque celle-ci est vraiment trop longue).

Answer (score 2):

Les oreilles de Grevisse seraient froissées comme celles de l'OP... ;-) (§50 d)

Si, pour ce qui est des lettres, *"qu'elles soient prises comme éléments de l'écriture ou comme représentant des sons, **l'usage est particulièrement hésitant**"*

C'est en revanche beaucoup plus codifié et donc clair dans le domaine mathématique :

"*Employées comme symboles en mathématiques, les lettres demandent la disjonction, de même que les dérivés ordinaux de n et de x.* (*1)

*La puissance m **de** a est le produit **de** m facteurs égaux à a.*"

---

<sup>(*1) auxquels j'ajouterais aussi volontiers ceux de *i*.</sup>