# Comment dit-on « de x » où x est une lettre ?

Tags: prononciation, alphabet, élision

Pour exemple, je corrige les examens et l'étudiant a omis la partie « f » du problème. Je voudrais écrire « pas de f » mais je suis pas sûr si on n'écrit pas « pas d'f » (parce que, même si la lettre f est une consonante, la prononciation de la lettre commence avec une voyelle).

Et aussi, quand on parle, est-ce-qu'on dit /dɛf/ ou /də.ɛf/ ?

Comment: (analogie: en anglais on dit et aussi on ecrit "an f" et on dit pas "a f" meme que le lettre "f" est un consonante)

Comment: Question très similaire: http://french.stackexchange.com/questions/1301/faut-il-faire-les-liaisons-avec-les-noms-de-lettres

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Je dirais que les deux sont admis à l'oral (en tout cas aucun des deux ne me choquerait, et je pense que j'utilise les deux formes indifféremment).

A l'écrit par contre, *pas d'f* fait vraiment bizarre, et *pas de f.* ou *pas de f)* sera vraiment plus compréhensible.

Answer (score 3):

Pourquoi ne dites-vous pas

> le f est manquant

ou bien

> omission du f

ou bien

> (f) omis

ou bien

> et (f)?

Comment: mais pas `l'f est manquant` ...

Comment: … ou « omission de l'f »…